# PyTorch - indices of corresponding values in another tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor, where I want to copy only some of the values (columnwise). The same values are in another tensor but in a random order. What I want, are the column indices from `tensor2` of the values of `tensor1`. Here is an example:

```
copy_ind = torch.tensor([0, 1, 3], dtype=torch.long)
tensor1 = torch.tensor([[4, 6, 5, 1, 8],[10, 0, 8, 2, 1]])
temp = torch.index_select(tensor1, 1, copy_ind) # values to copy
tensor2 = torch.tensor([[1, 4, 5, 6, 8],[2, 10, 8, 0, 1]], dtype=torch.long)
_, t_ind = torch.sort(temp[0], dim=0)
t2_ind = copy_ind[t_ind] # indices of tensor2
```

The output should be:

```
t2_ind = [1, 3, 0]
```

Here is another example where I want to get the values of the tensor according to `c1_new`:

```
c1 = torch.tensor([[6, 7, 7, 8, 6, 8, 9, 4, 7, 6, 1, 3],[5, 11, 5, 7, 2, 9, 5, 5, 7, 11, 10, 7]], dtype=torch.long)
copy_ind = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8], dtype=torch.long)
c1_new = torch.index_select(c1, 1, copy_ind)

indices = torch.as_tensor([[1, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9], [10, 7, 5, 2, 5, 11, 5, 7, 11, 7, 9, 5]])
values = torch.randn(12)
tensor = torch.sparse.FloatTensor(indices, values, (12, 12))

_, t_ind = torch.sort(c1[0], dim=0)
ind = t_ind[copy_ind] # should be [8, 6, 9, 10, 2, 7]
```

Unfortunately, the indices `ind` are not correct. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Could you show (*working code*) what you've tried so far?

Comment: I added some other example that shows what I want to do (get the tensor values for the copy indices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're ok with using a for loop you can use something like this: checking each column of your temp tensor against the columns of tensor2:

Edit: using `torch.prod` across dimension 1 to make sure both rows match

```
[torch.prod((temp.T[i] == tesnor2.T), dim=1).nonzero()[0] for i in range(temp.size(1))]
```

My output for your first example is `[tensor(1), tensor(3), tensor(0)]`

Comment: I am totally fine with every solution that works. Unfortunately, your approach does not return the correct indices for the second example. `ind  = [(c1_new.T[i] == indices.T).nonzero()[0, 0] for i in range(c1_new.size(1))]`does not return the correct indices and I don't know why.

Comment: ah I was not checking to make sure there was a match in both rows - this should work: (edited the answer as well to correct this)
`[torch.prod((c1_new.T[i] == indices.T), dim=1).nonzero()[0] for i in range(c1_new.size(1))]`